# Dual Monitor Setting for laptop Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display

I recently switched into Ubuntu 18.04 from Windows 10 on my laptop.
My goal is to connect additional monitor to my laptop.
I had been using my second monitor when I was using Windows 10, so I know this is not a hardware problem. I know there are plenty of questions posted in this forum, but none was helpful.

Here is my xrandr output

> Screen 0: minimum 320 X 200, current 3200 X 1800, maximum 8192 X 8192
>
> eDP-1 connected primary 3200X1800+0_0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm X 165mm
>
> DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Graphic Card: Intel HD Graphics 5500

On activities > settings > displays, there is no "detect display" feature or "configuration" feature. I can only see resolution, scale, refresh rate settings under "Built-in display".

I wonder what causes this problem.

1. Is this graphic card driver problem? If this is the case, how do I update Intel graphic card driver on Linux? I think it is up-to-date honestly.
2. HDMI port is not visible in my xrandr output unlike many others. How can I add one, or can I simply use DP-1?
3. If my system does not automatically detect the second monitor, should I statically edit xorg.conf?

Answer (score 1):

as you can tell, I am a noob in this Linux environment. After googling, downloading packages, and editting xorg.conf, nothing helped.

I updated into linux kernel 14.19 it suddenly shows hdmi port in my xrandr output and after that it automatically got connected to my monitor. Thank god, but I do not know why...